# How to move HTML element from one container to another with a Genshi match template?

Tags: python, xpath, genshi

From:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
  <a id="logo">Foo</a>
</div>
<div id="search">
...
</div>
</body>
```

To:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
  <a id="logo">Foo</a>

  <!-- inside #header now -->
  <div id="search">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is this doable with Genshi?

Comment: Judging from a quick look at the Genshi documentation I would say that that it is rather suitable to generate HTML from a template which is enriched with so-called "context" information. In your case I might consider XSLT to convert from one DOM to another.

Comment: I did arrive at a working solution, haven't had time to post it yet. Will do that shortly.